# How to change height of another container according to different classes

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have Html structure below

```
<div>
   <div class="experimental-bar experimental-bar-minimal"></div>
</div>
<div class="experimental-border">
   <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.experimental-bar { height: 50px; }
.experimental-bar-minimal {height: 25px; }

.container { height: ~"calc('100vh - 50px')"; }
```

I want to change height of container when experimental-bar-minimal class is called

I have used

```
div:has(.experimental-bar) + .experimental-border .f8-wi-container {
  height:  ~"calc('100vh - 50px')";
}
div:has(.experimental-bar-minimal) + .experimental-border .f8-wi-container {
  height:  ~"calc('100vh - 25px')";
}
```

Can anybody help me out. Thanks in advance

:has is not working

Comment: @zer00ne yes calc is working fine if I am using for .experimental-border.    Only problem is to select the parent and then adjacent selector

Answer (score 2):

There is no `<` Selector in CSS, and there is currently no option to style a parent element depending on one of its childs. At least not with vanilla CSS, I am not sure if this could be achieved with a preprocessor like Sass, Less or Stylus.

There acually is a `>` Selector, which selects only direct childs of the parent node. Please read the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) for further info.

---

Ther actually is the `:has` pseudo class, which works like the code below, but it is currently [**not supported**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has) by any browsers:

```
.parent:has(> child) {
    /* Style Rules */
}
```

Comment: :has is not working. Even if I use .parent:has(.class-x) {  }

Comment: I know, and I even mentioned **in bold** why it (currently) won't work in my answer!